# Set user friendly IP addresses for computers on my home network?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, remote-access, remote

I have a few machines on my home network that I ssh into. Windows, Mac, and Linux.

instead of `ssh name@123.0.0.1` every time I want to login to one of them it would be nice to set the IP as something user friendly. Possibly even the remote computers hostname?

Say my name is Matt and I want to login to my machine that has a hostname of thinkpad.

Could I `ssh matt@thinkpad` to login somehow?

Comment: Enable SMB and Netbios/Windbind name resolution on all of them... Either that or make shortcuts in your /etc/hosts file for each other machine, and setup static DHCP reservations for them to make it simpler. Any of these seem options?

Comment: Hmm I’m not sure I’m following completely. Could you break it down a little more simply?

Comment: For host name to ip address resolution you need a name resolution mechanism. Whether hosts files, DNS, LLMNR, whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Internet Engineering Task Force's standards-track protocol for doing this is IETF ZeroConf, which is an open standardization of Apple Bonjour. ZeroConf includes "multicast DNS" (mDNS) for hostname-to-IP-address resolution, and "DNS Service Discovery" (DNS-SD) for browsing/discovering devices and services available on the network.

Microsoft has implemented ZeroConf in Windows 10. Before that they had used proprietary technologies such as NetBIOS Name Resolution, WINS, and LLMNR. Those older protocols are still supported in Windows, but going with an open standard rather than a Microsoft proprietary technology is probably the better way forward on today's networks that aren't as Microsoft-dominated as they once were.

On Linux and other open source OSes, one of the most popular ZeroConf implementations is called Avahi, but there are others. I believe there is one called simply "mDNS", and Apple's own Bonjour daemon, known as mDNSResponder, is open source and available for many OSes.

Edited to add: Make sure you have Avahi or another ZeroConf implementation installed and running on your Linux devices. For macOS and Windows 10 you shouldn't have to do anything. Then you can do things like "ssh user@hostname.local" and it should just work.

Comment: This doesn't really give me an explanation on how to solve what I'm trying to achieve though.

Comment: @ChrisThomas Okay I've edited my Answer, but there's really nothing to it. Most OSes support ZeroConf out of the box now, but if your Linux distro didn't have it on by default, you may need to use your package manager to make sure Avahi is installed and running. Then you do pretty much as you said, but you may need to add ".local" to the end of the hostnames: "ssh user@host.local"

Comment: Got it now! Thanks for your answer.